# How to manage a BorderLayout with generic JPanel()

Tags: java, swing, jframe, border-layout

Im not sure how to reference to JPanel when it was declared like this.

This is the coding of the entire program: Everything works but the layout is not how I want it. adding BorderLayouts to it doesnt seem to work.

```
class FrameDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("CIT Test Program");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 250));
        frame.add(new JPanel()
        {{
            String[] tests = {"A+ Certification", "Network+ Certification", "Security+ Certification", "CIT Full Test Package"};
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(tests);
            TextArea text = new TextArea(5,10);
            add(new JLabel("Welcome to the CIT Test Program "));
            add(new JLabel("Please select which Test Package from the list below."));

            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
            JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
            JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
            menuBar.add(fileMenu);
            menuBar.add(editMenu);
            menuBar.add(helpMenu);
            JMenuItem newMenu = new JMenuItem("New  (Ctrl+N)");
            JMenuItem openMenu = new JMenuItem("Open  (Ctrl+O)");
            JMenuItem saveMenu = new JMenuItem("Save  (Ctrl+S)");
            JMenuItem exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Exit  (Ctrl+W)");
            JMenuItem cutMenu = new JMenuItem("Cut  (Ctrl+X)");
            JMenuItem copyMenu = new JMenuItem("Copy  (Ctrl+C)");
            JMenuItem pasteMenu = new JMenuItem("Paste  (Ctrl+V)");
            JMenuItem infoMenu = new JMenuItem("Help  (Ctrl+H)");
            fileMenu.add(newMenu);
            fileMenu.add(openMenu);
            fileMenu.add(saveMenu);
            fileMenu.add(exitMenu);
            editMenu.add(cutMenu);
            editMenu.add(copyMenu);
            editMenu.add(pasteMenu);
            helpMenu.add(infoMenu);
            this.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            this.add(text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
            add(new JButton("Select")
            {{
                addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
                    {
                        frame.dispose();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"IT WORKS!");

                    }
                });
            }});
        }});
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

    }
}
```

Not sure how to reference to JPanel to use BorderLayout.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

If you add a panel to a JFrame (using `add()` as you are doing here) , you can assume that it is being added as the `contentPanel`.  However, it is much better to be explicit. Instead of this:

```
frame.add(new JPanel()
{}
```

use this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
// add your stuff to the panel;
frame.add(panel);
```

EDIT:

after looking at your edit, what is clear is that you are initializing an anonymous class.  This is not generally bad practice, but here you are putting a lot of initialization code.  The code you are putting in is in a double-braced block, which in essence puts it into a static initializer.  It *seems* like a normal anonymous class, but it really isn't.  With that much code, it deserves its own class.  If you went so far as to code a new class, you should be fine.  I would suggest that you then define it as an extension of `JPanel` and in your own constructor pass a `new BorderLayout()` to the `super`.

EDIT 2:

if you create a brand new file/class named `Bar` and you coded it like this:

```
public class Bar extends JPanel {
    public Bar(final JFrame frame) {
        String[] tests = { "A+ Certification", "Network+ Certification",
                "Security+ Certification", "CIT Full Test Package" };
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(tests);
        TextArea text = new TextArea(5, 10);
        add(new JLabel("Welcome to the CIT Test Program "));
        add(new JLabel("Please select which Test Package from the list below."));

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu editMenu = new JMenu("Edit");
        JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        menuBar.add(editMenu);
        menuBar.add(helpMenu);
        JMenuItem newMenu = new JMenuItem("New  (Ctrl+N)");
        JMenuItem openMenu = new JMenuItem("Open  (Ctrl+O)");
        JMenuItem saveMenu = new JMenuItem("Save  (Ctrl+S)");
        JMenuItem exitMenu = new JMenuItem("Exit  (Ctrl+W)");
        JMenuItem cutMenu = new JMenuItem("Cut  (Ctrl+X)");
        JMenuItem copyMenu = new JMenuItem("Copy  (Ctrl+C)");
        JMenuItem pasteMenu = new JMenuItem("Paste  (Ctrl+V)");
        JMenuItem infoMenu = new JMenuItem("Help  (Ctrl+H)");
        fileMenu.add(newMenu);
        fileMenu.add(openMenu);
        fileMenu.add(saveMenu);
        fileMenu.add(exitMenu);
        editMenu.add(cutMenu);
        editMenu.add(copyMenu);
        editMenu.add(pasteMenu);
        helpMenu.add(infoMenu);
        this.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        add(new JButton("Select") {
            {
                addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.dispose();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "IT WORKS!");

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

All you would need to do to use it would be to call

```
  JPanel panel = new Bar(frame);
```

however, the goal here is to use a `BorderLayout`, so I would suggest that you put this call in to start:

```
 public Bar(final JFrame frame) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        .... everything else
 }
```

Comment: I have inserted the whole program code above so you can see the coding. adding it like your way I got about 33 errors.

Comment: ha. sorry about that.  i will look at your edit and give you some feedback.

Comment: Thanks, Don't be sorry. If your telling me something correct and I'm just not getting it then its my fault :P

Comment: Sorry, im kinda new to Java, I kind of understand that but not really. Where exactly where I code the new class, to me everything should be in the frame correct? If I create a new class wont it not be in the frame?

Comment: were you to code a new class, you could create a new instance just like you would any other new object.  it really is pretty easy.

Comment: Well, I believe I have coded this right, but I am getting an error

class frame2 is public, should be declared in a file named frame2.java

I coded it as 

public class frame2 extends JFrame 
{

}

Comment: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Bar()
location: class Bar
   JPanel panel = new Bar();

Comment: sorry, i had the frame in the constructor so i could keep the rest of your implementation untouched.

Answer (score 1):

On top of all answers already given... Your program has fundamental flaw. All manipulation with Swing components has to be done on EDT thread. So your code should be slightly different

```
class FrameDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                 void run() {
                    /// your code here
                 }    
         }); 
    }
}
```

Otherwise what happens is unpredictable. You can read more about it at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2007/jw-08-swingthreading.html

Comment: +1 Even when it's not the problem, it's the only way to rule it out.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding `BorderLayout` to it doesn't seem to work.

The default layout of a new `JPanel` is `FlowLayout`, as can be seen by resizing the frame. To see the difference, replace

```
frame.add(new JPanel()
```

with

```
frame.add(new JPanel(new BorderLayout())
```

As @akf suggests, lengthy static initialization using double braces can be obscure.